# CDN feature is not working in my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, cdn

To enable cdn in my wordpress site, I used plugins like WP supercache, W3 total cache, Breeze and CDN enabler. They just replace the domain with cdn url. But none of my CSS and JS are loading from CDN. I am using Azue CDN. Am I missing any thing to add in wp-config.php?

Answer (score 0):

> But none of my CSS and JS are loading from CDN.

Why? Maybe you are getting 404 errors on your website? While on your website press the F12 key, go to the console tab, and paste here what you can see there.

Comment: Are you sure you have checked "Errors" and "Warnings"? Can you post a link here?

Comment: I think it is not working when I logged in as admin but when I open it in incognito, the cdn is working.

Comment: I got 12 errors, all about CORS. All about fonts. Seems like every JS works fine so can you try to clear the cache?